# UseCalculate method, but don't recalculate data tables

Tags: vba, excel

I know you can set the calculation settings for the workbook, but I want to calculate the workbook ---and not data tables--- while running a VBA sub.

Generally, you can just call "Calculate" in your code and it acts as if you hit "F9" manually. How can you call "Calculate" and not recalc all data tables?

Comment: The [Worksheet.Calculate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834658.aspx) can be used to force calculation on "All open workbooks, A specific worksheet, A specified range".

Comment: pnuts: Yeah. Unfortunately, when you call the Calculate method, it seems to automatically do a full recalculation of the workbook, including data tables, regardless of the setting.

Comment: Jeeped: I'm trying to think of a clever way to use that functionality, but I really do need the whole workbook to refresh, just not the data tables.

Comment: as per Jeeped, what if you try to call calculate on the ranges only? (*for each sh in sheets sh.range.calculate*)

Comment: @A.S.H How can you be sure that all the precedents of the range being calculated have been calculated **before range is calculated**? Something on Sheet1 may refer to a Sheet2 cell containing a formula that hasn't been recalculated yet.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald wow, good point (+1)

Comment: @A.S.H Of course you could do you sheet.range calculate from the top down then the bottom up.  Calculation time might be worse than it was doing the data tables though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic
```

does what you want.

Comment: Great idea! But maybe is better the other way: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual `.